# Is it possible to set a Document ID when using Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose ElasticSearch Selivery

Tags: elasticsearch, document, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I might be interested into using Kinesis Analytics to transform some streams in real time to output them into an ES cluster.

However on the AWS documentation I do not see if I will be able to manually set a custom Document ID when Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose pushes it to ES.

Could someone confirm it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with firehose. Firehose auto generates ID for each message in Firehose. You may stream the data to Kinesis data streams and using lambda to set the document id.